# Can't find parent element in wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, html, alignment

I have been driving myself to Arkham Asylum status all day trying to figure out why my divs on the top of this site aren't working correctly

[touchoflunacy.com](http://www.touchoflunacy.com)

The divs that contain the links and the search aren't lining up correctly. I tried the usual suspects like adding a 20px border in different colors around the divs in the header to identify which one needed to be edited, but the borders don't show up so something is overriding them and for the life of me I can't figure out what.

I also attempted adding overflow:hidden;  to all the elements in the header (div#search div#header div#head bar etc. . . ) and in addition the #body element and the #wrapper to no effect.

I am fairly new to css so if anyone can tell me which element to change and what I would use I will bless you with eternal gratitude and a definite vote for the right answer(s)!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inspecting the elements in the Chrome dev tools or Firebug? Doing that will show you all the CSS styles currently being applied, and allows you to edit them in real time to figure out what changes you need to make.

To inspect just right-click on the element/area in question and select inspect element.

Comment: This helped a lot. I had been using firebug, but when I looked in chrome it helped me to highlight the issue much faster! There was a block tag and a padding tag in several elements that acted in concert. . .

Comment: I tried to add Thank you! but it wouldn't let me edit so Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the borders you are setting are showing up, try setting them to !important. That should help you debug the issue.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #F00 !important;
}
```

Comment: This helped to highlight issue and when combined with chrome helped me to identify issue quickly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I noticed is that you are floating your divs. I have had better luck using positioning to put divs where I would like them to go. Here is some example code (normally styling would be in css file)

```
<div style="position:relative;width:500px;height:28px;"><!-- Wrapper -->
 <div style="position:abolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;">CONTENT</div> <!--first div located top left -->
 <div style="position:abolute;top:0;left:400px;width:100px;">CONTENT</div> <!--second div located top right -->
</div>
```

This will allow for you to line up the divs to your exact layout.

Comment: And this helped to move it all the way up! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These guys are correct, you need to learn to use Firebug! It'll save you hours of time.

For exmaple with 10 seconds in firebug I can see that changing your CSS file located here /wp-content/w3tc/min/e4c7880c.00cd94.css at Line 2095 to the margin-top:14px to 0px; will get your search box to be inline with navigation menu.

I would also remove the clear:both; from the search element. It doesn't need it from what I can see. Instead I would add the clear:both; around Line 2054 to #inner to keep the next horizontal div from overlapping your floated header elements.

Then I'd remove the -22px top from the "#header #inner #logo a" element at Line 2062 as it causes more overlapping issues. Instead of the negative top, I'd adjust the height of the logo element to match your graphics file. So at line 2058 I'd change the height:99px to be height:122px which is the correct height for your logo. (Either that or resize your logo to be 99px in height).

There you have, I tested all of these changes on your site live with Firebug!

Comment: Thank you! I had gotten the divs to line up but they were still lower in the header and this helped move them up. Thank you!